# Mounting EFI system partition takes 2min+ on certain kernels

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mount, uefi

I had no problem with the current system setting until very recent I noticed that SystemD started to report mount failure on EFI system partition during boot.

Some information here: Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell XPS 15 9570, EFI system partition is on Samsung 970 PRO (which is /dev/nvme0n1p1), and I'm dual booting with Windows 10.

`/etc/fstab` looks like the following

```
/dev/nvme0n1p7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/nvme0n1p1  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile      none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sda1 /opt  ext4 defaults   0   1
```

After spending time on this, I found:

1. If I booted into maintenance mode and manually mount `/dev/nvme0n1p1` on `/boot/efi` as stated by `/etc/fstab`, it could take more than 2 minutes (and I think this is why SystemD time-out waiting for it)
2. I had run `fsck` on `/dev/nvme0n1p1` which reported no error.
3. The slow mounting problem only occurs if I start with kernel `4.15.0-177-generic` or `4.15.0-180-generic`. If I start with kernel `4.15.0-176-generic` or `4.15.0-175-generic`, then everything seems to be fine (mount is instantaneous), and I can confirm `/dev/nvme0n1p1` has been successfully mounted on `/boot/efi` after OS boot-up.

Comment: Generally better to use UUID (or labels) than device. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   &           
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  Boot-Repair cannot fix SystemD, but report should be useful. Boot-Repair's normal fix is reinstall of grub which may not be what you want.

Comment: Actually, initially all partitions are referred by UUID in fstab. After the SystemD failure, I changed to `/dev/...` but no use. Here is the summary [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QMs6FfqNK9/). I also strace the 2min+ mount command and found it was the mount system call that takes so long...

Comment: Okay, I finally get rid of this by using a newer kernel, though I still don't know why...